Gradle Build Fails: Could Not Resolve Dependencies with JitPack 401 Unauthorized
I am working on an Android project, and the Gradle build is failing to resolve several dependencies. Some dependencies are from JitPack, and I get a 401 Unauthorized error when Gradle tries to fetch them. Manually accessing the URLs in the browser also prompts for a username and password.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.ankushgrover:Hourglass:2.0.0.
   > Could not find com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:4.1.2.
   > Could not resolve com.tonyodev.fetch2:fetch2:3.0.12.
      > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/tonyodev/fetch2/fetch2/3.0.12/fetch2-3.0.12.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
   > Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1.
      > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/3.2.0-beta.1/android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.1.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
   

Edit:
I post you whole error message here for your perusal.
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.alxrm:audiowave-progressbar:0.9.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.mirrajabi:search-dialog:1.2.4.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.0.7.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.mukeshsolanki:Google-Places-AutoComplete-EditText:0.0.8.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.jitenderdev:countryutility:v1.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.judemanutd:autostarter:1.0.9.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.denizsubasi:CCView:0.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.hrskrs:InstaDotView:1.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.asksira.android:loopingviewpager:1.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.badoualy:stepper-indicator:1.0.7.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.Justson:Downloader:v5.0.0-androidx.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.BelooS:ChipsLayoutManager:v0.3.7.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.mancj:SlideUp-Android:2.2.8.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioRecorder:0.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.mmob-tech:mmob-client-android:v0.4.11.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.mmob-tech:mmob-client-android:v0.4.11.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.smhdk:KM-Recyclerview-Sticky-Header:v1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.Gkemon:Android-XML-to-PDF-Generator:2.6.8.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.BlacKCaT27:CurrencyEditText:2.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.Prashant-Chandel:Videoplayer-with-Vimeo-support:138257e15c.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.martinstamenkovski:ARIndicatorView:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.HamedTaherpour:ht-epub-reader-android:0.0.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.library:library:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app


The project is unable to download the dependencies. I could not find where it is going wrong.

jcenter() is deprecated, So just make sure you have below code in your project level gradle or settings.gradle.kts.
repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url = "https://verve.jfrog.io/artifactory/verve-gradle-dev" }  //.gradle 
       or 
       maven { url = uri("https://verve.jfrog.io/artifactory/verve-gradle-dev") } //kts
    }


tried and still same issue @Bashu
perhaps, i update the question with full errors. Would be helpful.

Could you please paste app level and project level gradle files ....?
